# how to customise codebuild/codepipeline notifications for slack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

What I am trying to achieve :- When a codebuild stage( action) is is successful, I want to send a notification to slack. **The real catch is in the message I want to send the codebuild build logs console link.**

In my current workflow when codebuild build is successful it sends default event to sns -> which triggers lambda -> slack

I am pretty sure there must be a way to receive codebuild build logs console link. Since URL for console link for every build is dynamic it cant be set static in my opinion.

Also:- Since this is not possible in default event, I was thinking to create a custom event in lambda ( after getting triggered from sns ) and add the console link and then pass on to slack.Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get log group link in two way.

- First one is on **Codebuild**  page you can create "*Create notification rule*" under "*Notify*" menu. Then you need to select only "**Succeeded**" on *Build State* of "**Events that trigger notifications**" then only two option to forward this message SNS or AWS Chatbot.
- When you choose SNS, attach a Lambda as subscription to this SNS.On lambda function you will get a message like
- `message = json.loads(event.Records[0].SNS.Message)` then get log from message `message.detail.additional-information.logs.deep-link`

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "EventSource": "aws:sns",
            "EventVersion": "1.0",
            "EventSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1: 3595xxx02761:codestar-notifications-test: 3648ad36-735e-4ce7-83ad-f5340d503c5d",
            "Sns": {
                "Type": "Notification",
                "MessageId": "df6e2eed-651e-5e21-b24b-72d5c7cdb684",
                "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1: 3595xxx02761:codestar-notifications-test",
                "Subject": None,
                "Message": "{"account": "3595xxx02761",
                "detailType": "CodeBuild Build State Change",
                "region": "us-east-1",
                "source": "aws.codebuild",
                "time": "2023-01-11T11:42:06Z",
                "notificationRuleArn": "arn:aws:codestar-notifications:us-east-1:3595xxx02761:notificationrule/e0b422a57a890c96aad913a2d9b0ca0d2f845223",
                "detail": {
                    "build-status": "SUCCEEDED",
                    "project-name": "test-build",
                    "build-id": "arn:aws:codebuild:us-east-1:3595xxx02761:build/test-build:88cfdd6f-0028-4bd6-ae43-ce44fcf5bbc2",
                    "additional-information": {
                        "cache": {
                            "type": "NO_CACHE"
                        },
                        "build-number": 1.0,
                        "timeout-in-minutes": 60.0,
                        "build-complete": true,
                        "initiator": "root",
                        "build-start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:41:22 AM",
                        "source": {
                            "git-clone-depth": 1.0,
                            "type": "NO_SOURCE"
                        },
                        "artifact": {
                            "location": ""
                        },
                        "environment": {
                            "image": "aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:4.0",
                            "privileged-mode": false,
                            "image-pull-credentials-type": "CODEBUILD",
                            "compute-type": "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL",
                            "type": "LINUX_CONTAINER",
                            "environment-variables": []
                        },
                        "logs": {
                            "group-name": "/aws/codebuild/test-build",
                            "stream-name": "88cfdd6f-0028-4bd6-ae43-ce44fcf5bbc2",
                            "deep-link": "https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#logEvent:group=/aws/codebuild/test-build;stream=88cfdd6f-0028-4bd6-ae43-ce44fcf5bbc2"
                        },
                        "phases": [
                            {
                                "phase-context": [],
                                "start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:41:22 AM",
                                "end-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:41:22 AM",
                                "duration-in-seconds": 0.0,
                                "phase-type": "SUBMITTED",
                                "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"
                            },
                            {
                                "phase-context": [],
                                "start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:41:22 AM",
                                "end-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:41:24 AM",
                                "duration-in-seconds": 1.0,
                                "phase-type": "QUEUED",
                                "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"
                            },
                            {
                                "phase-context": [
                                    ": "
                                ],
                                "start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:41:24 AM",
                                "end-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:41:57 AM",
                                "duration-in-seconds": 33.0,
                                "phase-type": "PROVISIONING",
                                "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"
                            },
                            {
                                "phase-context": [
                                    ": "
                                ],
                                "start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:41:57 AM",
                                "end-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM",
                                "duration-in-seconds": 2.0,
                                "phase-type": "DOWNLOAD_SOURCE",
                                "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"
                            },
                            {
                                "phase-context": [
                                    ": "
                                ],
                                "start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM",
                                "end-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM",
                                "duration-in-seconds": 0.0,
                                "phase-type": "INSTALL",
                                "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"
                            },
                            {
                                "phase-context": [
                                    ": "
                                ],
                                "start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM",
                                "end-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM",
                                "duration-in-seconds": 0.0,
                                "phase-type": "PRE_BUILD",
                                "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"
                            },
                            {
                                "phase-context": [
                                    ": "
                                ],
                                "start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM",
                                "end-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM",
                                "duration-in-seconds": 0.0,
                                "phase-type": "BUILD",
                                "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"
                            },
                            {
                                "phase-context": [
                                    ": "
                                ],
                                "start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM",
                                "end-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM",
                                "duration-in-seconds": 0.0,
                                "phase-type": "POST_BUILD",
                                "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"
                            },
                            {
                                "phase-context": [
                                    ": "
                                ],
                                "start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM",
                                "end-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM",
                                "duration-in-seconds": 0.0,
                                "phase-type": "UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS",
                                "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"
                            },
                            {
                                "phase-context": [
                                    ": "
                                ],
                                "start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM",
                                "end-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:04 AM",
                                "duration-in-seconds": 4.0,
                                "phase-type": "FINALIZING",
                                "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"
                            },
                            {
                                "start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:04 AM",
                                "phase-type": "COMPLETED"
                            }
                        ],
                        "queued-timeout-in-minutes": 480.0
                    },
                    "current-phase": "COMPLETED",
                    "current-phase-context": "[: ]",
                    "version": "1"
                },
                "resources": [
                    "arn:aws:codebuild:us-east-1:3595xxx02761:build/test-build:88cfdd6f-0028-4bd6-ae43-ce44fcf5bbc2"
                ],
                "additionalAttributes": {}
            }", "Timestamp": "2023-01-11T11: 42: 11.284Z", "SignatureVersion": "1", "Signature": "QyI4CAlszBYE8MJLy+Wwxpn/Ie4kFYigaaRzPEAz4v6vFDE7x7TjaG7yWSiLNGFnBXLpg6Cl3/B70eTLJKmNv/5adXOsDz0Pw53iAcXumLsgtSuPoCpG3zISPvgR1nLBfZia7fv0w02C6d9LrjQq5v8jRZi/GJUt5frigL4Tfq3Q+wAFkmjl31GfxjcSTc0X7ujO1t+/qRIcVaa+XXOhLcDTWG9Q0qWMh0jyf5/126d3CUSRhlM6v9OzqZ4w5a/qEkq+XMaH2ElDdF9rEN+D+GayqltA4hkxwERsbvNyHmG7LBthWChezxfohJ88/O3nIvCsyv1IX9MNgyeWcOxHnA==", "SigningCertUrl": "https: //sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-56e67fcb41f6fec09b0196692625d385.pem", "UnsubscribeUrl": "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:3595xxx02761:codestar-notifications-test:3648ad36-735e-4ce7-83ad-f5340d503c5d", "MessageAttributes": {}}}]}
```

- Other option using **EventBridge** Rule, using an event pattern like

```
{
 "source": ["aws.codebuild"],
 "detail-type": ["CodeBuild Build State Change"],
 "detail": {
   "build-status": ["SUCCEEDED"]
 }
}
```

your answer on the event field `event.detail.additional-information.logs.deep-link` is link for log stream.

```
{
    "version": "0", 
    "id": "1bdc2d34-2b5a-4de9-8738-bd38ef2de265", 
    "detail-type": "CodeBuild Build State Change", 
    "source": "aws.codebuild", 
    "account": "3595xxx02761", 
    "time": "2023-01-11T11:42:06Z", 
    "region": "us-east-1", 
    "resources":  ["arn:aws:codebuild:us-east-1:3595xxx02761:build/test-build:88cfdd6f-0028-4bd6-ae43-ce44fcf5bbc2"], 
    "detail": {
        "build-status": "SUCCEEDED", 
        "project-name": "test-build", 
        "build-id": "arn:aws:codebuild:us-east-1:3595xxx02761:build/test-build:88cfdd6f-0028-4bd6-ae43-ce44fcf5bbc2", 
        "additional-information": {
            "cache": {"type": "NO_CACHE"}, 
            "build-number": 1.0, 
            "timeout-in-minutes": 60.0, 
            "build-complete": True, 
            "initiator": "root", 
            "build-start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:41:22 AM", 
            "source": {"buildspec": "version: 0.2\n\nphases:\n  build:\n    commands:\n       - echo "Hello world"\n", "git-clone-depth": 1.0, "type": "NO_SOURCE"}, 
            "artifact": {"location": ""}, 
            "environment": {"image": "aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:4.0", "privileged-mode": False, "image-pull-credentials-type": "CODEBUILD", "compute-type": "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL", "type": "LINUX_CONTAINER", "environment-variables": []}, 
            "logs": {"group-name": "/aws/codebuild/test-build", "stream-name": "88cfdd6f-0028-4bd6-ae43-ce44fcf5bbc2", "deep-link": "https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#logEvent:group=/aws/codebuild/test-build;stream=88cfdd6f-0028-4bd6-ae43-ce44fcf5bbc2"}, 
            "phases": [{"phase-context": [], "start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:41:22 AM", "end-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:41:22 AM", "duration-in-seconds": 0.0, "phase-type": "SUBMITTED", "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"}, {"phase-context": [], "start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:41:22 AM", "end-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:41:24 AM", "duration-in-seconds": 1.0, "phase-type": "QUEUED", "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"}, {"phase-context": [": "], "start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:41:24 AM", "end-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:41:57 AM", "duration-in-seconds": 33.0, "phase-type": "PROVISIONING", "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"}, {"phase-context": [": "], "start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:41:57 AM", "end-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM", "duration-in-seconds": 2.0, "phase-type": "DOWNLOAD_SOURCE", "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"}, {"phase-context": [": "], "start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM", "end-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM", "duration-in-seconds": 0.0, "phase-type": "INSTALL", "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"}, {"phase-context": [": "], "start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM", "end-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM", "duration-in-seconds": 0.0, "phase-type": "PRE_BUILD", "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"}, {"phase-context": [": "], "start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM", "end-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM", "duration-in-seconds": 0.0, "phase-type": "BUILD", "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"}, {"phase-context": [": "], "start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM", "end-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM", "duration-in-seconds": 0.0, "phase-type": "POST_BUILD", "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"}, {"phase-context": [": "], "start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM", "end-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM", "duration-in-seconds": 0.0, "phase-type": "UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS", "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"}, {"phase-context": [": "], "start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:00 AM", "end-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:04 AM", "duration-in-seconds": 4.0, "phase-type": "FINALIZING", "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"}, {"start-time": "Jan 11, 2023 11:42:04 AM", "phase-type": "COMPLETED"}], 
            "queued-timeout-in-minutes": 480.0
        }, 
        "current-phase": "COMPLETED", 
        "current-phase-context": "[: ]", 
        "version": "1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you even I figured out this way btw I wanted to find codebuild build log link which is present in the console of codebuild not the cloudwatch link but I was able to find this through stream name in the output thank you it helped